# Horizontal Alignment When Using Overset with Superscript

Tags: alignment, superscripts, overset

I have the following problem. In the latex snippet below the superscript "(+)" is slighty higher for the complex conjugate c (c with star on top) than with the normal c. How can I align this so both are at the same height?

```
\documentclass[8pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:distribution_fn}
f_r(\bar{p},t) ~=~ \langle ~ 0_{\text{in}} ~ | ~ \overset{*}{c}^{(+)}_{\bar{p}r}(t) ~ c^{(-)}_{\bar{p}r}(t) ~ | ~ 0_{\text{in}} ~ \rangle
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this right for you? `\overset{*}{c}{}^{(+)}`

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! And an easy solution on top of that, thanks!

Comment: @Whitechapel: There is no need to use `~` around operators/symbols since the spacing around binary operators/relations will be set as needed. I know it might feel close to you, but these settings are quite common. Using it might stem from a historic use of `eqnarray` where additional space was inserted. Of course, your choice might be personal preference, and that's okay too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `accents`:

```
\documentclass[8pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\cstar}{\accentset{*}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:distribution_fn}
f_r(\bar{p},t) =
\langle 0_{\mathrm{in}}
\mid
\cstar^{(+)}_{\bar{p}r}(t) \, c^{(-)}_{\bar{p}r}(t)
\mid
0_{\mathrm{in}} \rangle
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed all `~` commands and used `\mid` for spacing the vertical bars. Between the two big symbols I inserted `\,`. On the other hand, this doesn't seem really necessary. Here's the output without manual spacing.

[image]

Comment: This looks good, I think I will adopt your suggestion. What exactly is the advantage of \mid over ~ ?

Comment: @Whitechapel It doesn’t require you to remember adding manually the spacing. I realize now that there is still another `~` to remove. If you feel that some space is necessary there, use `\,`.